# Is there a way to test an instance variable in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties, instance-variables, ocmock

I need to test an instance variable in Objective C.

I have this snippet in `myViewController.m`

```
@implementation myViewController
{
NSView *myView;
}
```

I need to add a test in `myViewControllerTest.mm` that tests a case when `myView.window` happens to be `nil`

```
-(void) myTest 
{
// 1. assert condition 1 is true
// 2. mock myView.window and set it to nil OR set myView.window directly to nil
// 3. assert condition 1 is false
}
```

I'd like to know the best approach to achieve step 2 in the test. Approaches I tried:

- Add an explicit setter `- (void)setMyView:(NSView*)myView` just for the unit test purpose and use that in myTest.
  I have a feeling that this is not a good way.
- make `myView` as a property and put it in `myViewController.h` so that I'll have a setter without explicitly defining one.
- Unsuccessful attempt at mocking using OCMock. (need to explore further)

Please suggest what the best approach is and what are the pros/cons of them.
Thanks !

**Edit : Answer I ended up using in my test file.**

`[myViewController setValue:nil forKeyPath:@"myViewControl.window"];`

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-BAJEAIEE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add setter only for testing in your test file `myViewControllerTest.mm`

This has no effect to your production code.

like below using Extension

```c
// Write this in test file.
@interface MyViewController(Test)
- (void)setMyView:(NSView *)myView;
@end
```

or just use `valueForKey:` to get private field.

```c
-(void) myTest 
{
  id myViewController = ...;
  NSView *myView = [myViewController valueForKey:@"myView"];
  myView.window = nil;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: As the maintainer of OCMock I upvoted this answer. Seems like a more sensible approach than trying to mock an accessor.